# zip multiple values with single value

Tags: python, list

I have a list:

```
ave=['Avg']
```

and another one:

```
range(0,24)
```

How do I zip them so I will have:

```
[0,'Avg',1,'Avg',....23,'Avg']
```

It is preferred not to have each entry in brackets ie

```
[[0,'Avg'],[...]]
```

since I would later want to make that list into a CSV.

I know I could do it with a simple loop, but is there a more clean-cut way? a function maybe?

Comment: Thank you everyone for answers; All of your answers are functional and pretty; I went with the most minimalist though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think a loop like this is clean enough:

```
ave=['Avg']
lst = []
for x in range(24):
    lst.extend((x,ave[0]))
```

`lst`:

```
>>> lst
[0, 'Avg', 1, 'Avg', 2, 'Avg', 3, 'Avg', 4, 'Avg', 5, 'Avg', 6, 'Avg', 7, 'Avg', 8, 'Avg', 9, 'Avg', 10, 'Avg', 11, 'Avg', 12, 'Avg', 13, 'Avg', 14, 'Avg', 15, 'Avg', 16, 'Avg', 17, 'Avg', 18, 'Avg', 19, 'Avg', 20, 'Avg', 21, 'Avg', 22, 'Avg', 23, 'Avg']
```

Comment: why put `Avg` in a list?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I don't know, ask user3761534.

Answer (score 4):

It's easy enough to get the pairings as you noted, but you can then use `itertools.chain()` to unwrap the pairings:

```
from itertools import chain

fields = ['Avg']
indexes = range(0, 24)

groups = [[i] + fields for i in indexes]

flat_list = list(chain.from_iterable(groups))
```

Answer (score 4):

Using [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) and [`itertools.izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest):

```
>>> from itertools import chain, izip_longest
>>> ave = ['Avg']
>>> r = range(0,24)
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(izip_longest(r, ave, fillvalue=ave[0])))
[0, 'Avg', 1, 'Avg', 2, 'Avg', 3, 'Avg', 4, 'Avg', 5, 'Avg', 6, 'Avg', 7, 'Avg', 8, 'Avg', 9, 'Avg', 10, 'Avg', 11, 'Avg', 12, 'Avg', 13, 'Avg', 14, 'Avg', 15, 'Avg', 16, 'Avg', 17, 'Avg', 18, 'Avg', 19, 'Avg', 20, 'Avg', 21, 'Avg', 22, 'Avg', 23, 'Avg']
>>>
```

Without importing, using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) would be a slightly less efficient but still workable solution:

```
>>> ave = ['Avg']
>>> r = range(0,24)
>>> [y for x in r for y in (x, ave[0])]
[0, 'Avg', 1, 'Avg', 2, 'Avg', 3, 'Avg', 4, 'Avg', 5, 'Avg', 6, 'Avg', 7, 'Avg', 8, 'Avg', 9, 'Avg', 10, 'Avg', 11, 'Avg', 12, 'Avg', 13, 'Avg', 14, 'Avg', 15, 'Avg', 16, 'Avg', 17, 'Avg', 18, 'Avg', 19, 'Avg', 20, 'Avg', 21, 'Avg', 22, 'Avg', 23, 'Avg']
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

## Using generator

Generator is a function, which does not return single result, but can yields multiple ones during whatever run it uses.

Having a function `gen` as follows:

```
def gen(itm, nums):
    for num in nums:
        yield num
        yield itm

>>> g = gen("Avg", range(0, 4))
>>> list(g)
[0, 'Avg', 1, 'Avg', 2, 'Avg', 3, 'Avg']
```

The `list` function forced the `g` generator instance to iterate through all available values until there is no more items to yield and return them in a list.

## Consuming from generator by `next()`

You can use the generator also in alternative ways using `next`, getting values just one by one:

```
>>> g = gen("Avg", range(0, 4))
>>> g.next()
0
>>> g.next()
'Avg'
>>> g.next()
1
>>> g.next()
'Avg'
>>> g.next()
2
>>> g.next()
'Avg'
>>> g.next()
3
>>> g.next()
'Avg'
>>> g.next()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-d7e53364a9a7> in <module>()
----> 1 g.next()

StopIteration:
```

Note, that we get `StopIteration` exception when there is no more values to yield.

Another important detail is, that a generator has it's internal state and you have to initialize it to get values again from the first to the last one. Exhausted instance of generator will not yield any more values.

Answer (score 1):

Another option

```
 ave = ['Ave']
 m = range(24)
 [a for b in [(x, ave[0]) for x in m] for a in b]
 [0, 'Ave', 1, 'Ave', 2, 'Ave', 3, 'Ave', 4, 'Ave', 5, 'Ave', 6, 'Ave', 7, 'Ave', 8, 'Ave', 9, '
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fun solution:

```
from operator import add
reduce(add, zip(range(0, 24), ['Avg']*24))
```